# How to paint a line of decals on object with Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have [This Example](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/py6bo3jz/35/) , as you can see - the event that used for adding decals to the object is 'pointerup', like in the following function :

```
    window.addEventListener( 'pointerup', function ( event ) {

    if ( moved === false ) {

        checkIntersection( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        if ( intersection.intersects ) shoot();

    }

} );
```

I wonder how can i add decals while the mouse/ pointer are pressed - so if i could do it - it will be like the action of drawing - which is what i want to achieve...

The problem is that i cant figure out which event and function should i use for repeatedly track each move and append it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that i cant figure out which event and function should i use for repeatedly track each move and append it...

You can do this by combining `pointerdown`, `pointerup` and `pointermove` event listeners. Use the first and second one to manage a boolean variable e.g. `drawing`. On `pointerdown`, you set it to `true`. On `pointerup`, you set it to `false`. You then know when the interaction is in the drawing state.

In the `pointermove` event listener, you check for `drawing`. If set to `true`, you execute the actual drawing logic. The official `three.js` example [webgl_materials_texture_canvas](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_canvas) demonstrates this workflow. The idea of the example is to draw on a canvas which is used as a texture for a cube.